# Params ID - Couldn't find category with id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? "Couldn't find Category with 'id'="
I have 2 models of images and categories. In the model, the image belongs_to and in the model, the category is has_many.

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController   
def new
    @category = Category.new   end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    if @category.save
      flash[:notice] = "Stworzono kategorię"

      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end  

end
def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.all
    @images = @category.images
  end

      
  def destroy
  end

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.all
    @images = @category.images
  end
```

SHOW.HTML.ERB

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="galeria">
        <h2><%= @category.name %><small class="pull-right"><%= link_to 'Edytuj', edit_category_path, class: 'btn btn-warning' %></small></h2>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your controller is expecting params :id to be passed to show action. URL should look something like ‘/categories/1 ‘ if you did not change anything. Please share the logs

Answer (score 0):

Your link need to have a category_id like :

```
<%= link_to 'Edytuj', edit_category_path(@category.id), class: 'btn btn-warning' %>
```